# CSS triangle, Opera wrong display:

Tags: html, css, opera

CSS for elements, [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QYK6u/)

```
#scroll_jump 
{
        margin-top: 310px;
        position: fixed;
        margin-left: 20px;
        display: none;
}

#jump_link 
{
        display: block;
        width: 70px;
        height: 20px;
        background: #BBDAF7;
        color:white;
        font-family: Arial,Liberation Sans,DejaVu Sans,sans-serif;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-align: center;
        padding-left: -1px;
}

#jump_link:after 
{
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border: 35px solid;
        border-bottom-color:#BBDAF7;
        border-top-color:white;
        border-left-color:#ffffff ;
        border-right-color: #ffffff;

        top: 0;
        margin-top: -70px;
        left: 49%;
        margin-left: -35px; /* adjust for border width */
}
```

Correct display: Chrome, Firefox, IE.

How it looks in Opera:

[image]

P.S. So far Opera created much more troubles, than IE!!!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this:

```
#jump_link:after{
    left: 49%;
    margin-left: -35px;
}
```

all you need is this:

```
#jump_link:after{
    left: 0;
}
```

and then it works just fine in grand ol' Opry (as well as the other browsers). :-)

Answer (score 1):

It's about your :after pseudo-element. For 'left' you're using a percentage. Most browsers take this to mean a percentage of the main element, Opera will take this a percentage of the parent. Use pixels if you can for the left position (e.g. 35px).

Comment: Oh, @ralph.m's answer is probably better than mine. Also, note that Opera is changing to the webkit engine pretty soon, which means the behaviour is going to more closely match safari and Chrome.